# Kinect v2 HandState always unknown

Tags: kinect

```
    if (body.IsTracked)
                    {
                        //if (body.HandLeftState.Equals(HandState.Lasso))
                            //lbHandState.Content = body.HandLeftState;
                            // Find the left hand state
                            switch (body.HandLeftState)
                            {
                                case HandState.Open:
                                    lbHandState.Content = "Open";
                                    break;
                                case HandState.Closed:
                                    lbHandState.Content = "Closed";
                                    break;
                                case HandState.Lasso:
                                    lbHandState.Content = "Lasso";
                                    break;
                                case HandState.Unknown:
                                    lbHandState.Content = "Unknown";
                                    break;
                                case HandState.NotTracked:
                                    lbHandState.Content = "NotTracked";
                                    break;
                                default:
                                    break;
                            }
```

Above is my code after the BodyFrame is arrived.

I have tried the SDKs public preview in Aug and Sep. All of then can not track the HandState.

Turn to the Kinect Studio, the hands's circles are always black which cannot track the HandState.

I don't know what's wrong with my SDK, the problem remains even after I reinstalled the SDK.

Anyone in Kinect team can provide help?

Comment: I've the same issue, when I resolve this problem I'll tell you what was wrong.

Comment: I even have contacted with the Microsoft team, it seems have some way to solve it if you follow the thread:  https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/dd14d569-a03c-4abc-b740-f7f920746e30/handstate-error-in-1408-1409-sdk-please-check?forum=kinectv2sdk

Comment: I fixed this by updating my GPU driver as suggested in the form Bruce Yo provided above

Comment: Should be the problem of the PC. As I change to other PCs, the code works fine. Anyway, Congrats!

Comment: hey @BruceYo you should post that as answer, it worked for me and that way it will be easily noticed

Comment: Updating the GPU driver also worked for you? @wiped

Comment: yes, it now tracks hand states flawlessly using ofxKinectForWindows2 with Kinect SDK 2.0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The issue was due to the graphics card driver. I uninstalled the OEM driver and downloaded the professional driver from the [manufacturer website (NVIDIA)](http://www.nvidia.com/download/index.aspx). Now HandState is working. Make sure your driver is up to date and that you have the driver from the manufacturer instead of the standard one installed by Windows.

Answer (score -2):

Change the PC, maybe your PC not has some iusse with the kinect v2.